# Building a RFID log-in system in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build an automatic attendance site using RFID, currently MySQL already records the time and date a student enters the campus, but I want each attendance tagged as either "late" or "on-time" using the time they entered the campus.

For example Student A taps his RFID at the gate at 7:11 AM this would be tagged as LATE, Student B taps her RFID at the gate at 6:55AM and this would tagged as early in MySQL.

I am a beginner in JavaScript, MySQL and jQuery so I don't know which code to use. I'm self taught so I try to search for tutorials online, but for this one it seems that I cannot find tutorials for it.

Here's my code for the RFID tag.

```
<?php
require_once 'admin/connect.php';
$student = $_POST['student'];
$time = date("H:i", strtotime("+8 HOURS"));
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+8 HOURS"));
$q_student = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `student_no` = '$student'") or die(mysqli_error());
$f_student = $q_student->fetch_array();
$student_name = $f_student['firstname']." ".$f_student['lastname'];
$conn->query("INSERT INTO `time` VALUES('', '$student', '$student_name', '$time', '$date')") or die(mysqli_error());
echo "<h3 class = 'text-muted'>".$student_name." <label class = 'text-info'>at  ".date("h:i a", strtotime($time))."</label></h3>";
```

This is what my database currently looks like when a students taps his/her ID:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/II7PM.jpg

Hi! I'm Getting MYSQL Errors i dont know how to troubleshoot
.\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#4196: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getSortedColumnMessage(
,
string '`student_name`',
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#1666: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTable(
,
array,
array,
boolean true,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#1468: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean false,
integer 0,
integer 0,
boolean true,
,
array,
boolean true,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2250: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getQueryResponseForNoResultsReturned(
array,
string 'db_sars',
string 'time',
NULL,
integer 0,
,
NULL,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
,
string 'SELECT `date`, student_no, student_name, `time`, CASE WHEN time > \'07:00\' THEN \'LATE\' ELSE \'ON TIME\' END AS tag FROM `time` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND `time` BETWEEN \'05:00\' AND \'09:00\' ORDER BY `date`, `student_name`',
NULL,
)
.\import.php#758: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean false,
string 'db_sars',
string 'time',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'tbl_structure.php',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT `date`, student_no, student_name, `time`, CASE WHEN time > \'07:00\' THEN \'LATE\' ELSE \'ON TIME\' END AS tag FROM `time` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND `time` BETWEEN \'05:00\' AND \'09:00\' ORDER BY `date`, `student_name`',
NULL,
NULL,
)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please be warned that this code is widely open to SQL injection

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate [of your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382056/javascript-mark-as-late-if-beyond-711am)?

Comment: Hi! Currently stuck with this error. "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

Answer (score 0):

(Please avoid using images to show key parts of your problem).

It looks like your `time` table contains these columns:

```
student
student_name
time
date
```

It looks like you have no information about whether a student is arriving or departing. That makes your logic a little trickier.  Let's assume any row of your `time` table between `05:00` and `09:00` means an arrival, and that any arrival after `07:00` is considered late.  You can get a list of student arrivals in the last week with this query. They'll have the tag `LATE` when needed or `ON TIME` otherwise.

```
  SELECT `date`, student, student_name, `time`,
         CASE WHEN time > '07:00' THEN 'LATE' ELSE 'ON TIME' END AS tag
    FROM `time`
   WHERE  `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
     AND `time` BETWEEN '05:00' AND '09:00'
    ORDER BY `date`, `student`
```

I guess that's what you mean by tagging each attendance.

**Edit** If you want to show these tags `LATE` on your web site, you need no extra column in the database. Just use a query like the one I showed; the query itself contains the rule defining lateness and applies the tag. Then display the results from the query.  It's generally not a good idea to alter a table to insert conditions you can derive from the existing content of each row. (That's different if you have hundreds of millions of rows and must [denormalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) your table to gain performance. But you're nowhere near that point.)

**Pro tip** Don't use reserved words like `DATE` and `TIME` for the names of tables or columns. Doing so makes it harder to track down bugs.

Comment: Hi, will i need to make another column for this on the Database and put it on the php file so the tags appear on the website? I don't quite get it, I'm trying to add it to my PHP code so that it appears on the website when an admin checks for the attendance of the student.

Comment: Hi again, sorry you must think i'm really stupid but how do i add that to my code on my MySQL or PHP file? I'm really really sorry.